# Kotlin dialog/alert without MainActivity, without custom layout

Tags: android, kotlin, alert, android-alertdialog

After inspecting and trying to implement at least 8 different suggested solutions to display a message box/dialog/alert in android studio 3.2.1, I've noticed I have been unable to find any suggested solution that either:

1. Works without having a main activity and/or without a button that is pressed before it shows the message.
2. Complemented with how to import the required libraries.

6 out of 8 of my attempts are currently bottlenecked at at either of those two points. Individually troubleshooting each single one of those attempts have not led to a working case for a single approach. Therefore I have the question:

**How can one display the value of a string accountType** in [GateKeeper.kt](https://github.com/jecsan/gatekeeper/blob/e84c48638a2f86d50d47030563948714c9b9f673/gatekeeper/src/main/java/com/greyblocks/gatekeeper/GateKeeper.kt)?

This summarizes my attempts so far:

```
package com.greyblocks.gatekeeper

import android.accounts.Account
import android.accounts.AccountManager
import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import java.io.File
import java.io.PrintWriter

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
//import android.support.design
//import com.greyblocks.gatekeepersample.MainActivity
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.content.ContextWrapper
import android.widget.EditText


import android.util.Log
import com.google.android.material.R.id.title
import com.greyblocks.gatekeeper.R.id.info


@Suppress("unused")
open class GateKeeper(private val accountManager: AccountManager,
                      private val accountType: String) {

    fun getCurrentAccount(): Account? {

        val accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(accountType)
        if (accounts.isNotEmpty()) {
            return accounts[0]
        }
        return null
    }



    fun getAuthToken(): String? {
        val account = getCurrentAccount()
        return account?.let { accountManager.peekAuthToken(getCurrentAccount(), AccountAuthenticator.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS) }
    }


    fun enter(user: String, password: String?, authToken: String, userData: Bundle? = null) {
        if (getCurrentAccount() != null) {
            logout()
        }
        accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(Account(user, accountType), password, userData)
        accountManager.setAuthToken(getCurrentAccount(), AccountAuthenticator.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS, authToken)
    }

    fun saveUserData(key: String, value: Long) {
        accountManager.setUserData(getCurrentAccount(), key, value.toString())
    }

    fun saveUserData(key: String, value: Int) {
        accountManager.setUserData(getCurrentAccount(), key, value.toString())
    }

    fun saveUserData(key: String, value: String) {
        accountManager.setUserData(getCurrentAccount(), key, value)
    }

    fun getUserData(key: String, defaultData: String? = null): String? {
        return accountManager.getUserData(getCurrentAccount(), key) ?: defaultData
    }

    fun getLong(key: String): Long {
        return accountManager.getUserData(getCurrentAccount(), key)?.toLongOrNull() ?: 0L
    }

    fun getInt(key: String): Int {
        return accountManager.getUserData(getCurrentAccount(), key)?.toIntOrNull() ?: 0
    }

    fun logout() {

        //try to write something to screen:
        print("Maximum of a or b is " );
        Log.d("TAG", "message")
        println("other message")

        //info("London is the capital of Great Britain")
//        debug(5) // .toString() method will be executed
//        warn(null) // "null" will be printed
//        toast("Hello, ${name.text}!")
        fun print(message: Any?) {}
        var message:String
        message="D";
        fun print(message: String) {}


        //try to write something to file:
        //writeToTxt(accountType); Crashes upon pressing logout

        if (getCurrentAccount() != null) {


            accountManager.invalidateAuthToken(accountType, getAuthToken())
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                accountManager.removeAccountExplicitly(getCurrentAccount())
            } else {
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                accountManager.removeAccount(getCurrentAccount(), null, null)
            }
        }

    }

    @Suppress("MemberVisibilityCanBePrivate")
    fun isLoggedIn(): Boolean {
        return getAuthToken() != null
    }

    fun checkUserAuth(activity: Activity) {
        if (!isLoggedIn()) {
            accountManager.addAccount(accountType, AccountAuthenticator.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS, null, null, activity,
                    null, null)
            activity.finish()
        }
    }

    //Attempt 0: Can't find an import for alert
//    fun messageBox(String inputString){
//        alert("Testing alerts") {
//            title = "Alert"
//            yesButton { toast("Yess!!!") }
//            noButton { }
//        }.show()
//    }

    //Attempt 1: Problem: needs to be called from an object "this" which does not exist in this file.
//    fun showNormalAlert(v: View){
//        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Kotlin Study").setMessage("Alert Dialog")
//                .setPositiveButton("Confirm", { dialog, i ->
//                    val applicationContext=null;
//                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Hello Friends", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
//                })
//                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", { dialog, i -> })
//        dialog.show()
//    }

    //Attempt 2: Can't find somefile.txt
//    fun writeToTxt(input: String) {
//        File("somefile.txt").printWriter().use { out ->
//            out.println("${input}, ${"text1"}")
//
//        }
//    }

    //Attempt 3: can't find file.txt
    fun writeToTxt(input: String) {
        PrintWriter("file.txt").use {
            for (i in 1..5) {
                println(i)
            }
        }
    }
        //Attempt 4: Do not know yet how to create a parentview in the middle of this code
//    fun writeToTxt(input: String) {
//        Snackbar.make(parentView, "The string = ", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
//    }

        //Attempt 5: Don't yet know how to import the design
//    fun onSNACK(view: View){
//        //Snackbar(view)
//        val snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action",
//                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null)
//        snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.BLUE)
//        val snackbarView = snackbar.view
//        snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
//        val textView =
//                snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text) as TextView
//        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
//        textView.textSize = 28f
//        snackbar.show()
//    }


        //Attempt 6: Don't yet know how to generate the AdapterView<*>
//    fun showPopup(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View,
//                    position: Int, rowId: Long) {
//        val result: String;
//        val context = ContextWrapper(null)
//        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(ContextWrapper(null)).show()
//        val adb = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
//
//        adb.setTitle("List")
//        adb.setMessage(" selected Item is=" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position))
//        adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
//        adb.show()
//        Snackbar.make(view, "Invalid username or password", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
//    }

    //Attempt 7: Crashes App upon opening
//    @Throws(Exception::class)
//    fun shouldSetView() {
//        val context = ContextWrapper(null)
//        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
//        val view = EditText(context)
//        builder.setView(view)
//
//        val alert = builder.create()
//        //shadowOf(alert).getView()
//        view as View
//    }

    //Attempt 8: Can't import inflate
//        fun showNewNameDialog() {
//            val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
//            val inflater = this.layoutInflater
//            val dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null)
//            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView)
//
//            val editText = dialogView.findViewById<View>(R.id.editTextName) as EditText
//
//            dialogBuilder.setTitle("Custom dialog")
//            dialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter Name Below")
//            dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Save", { dialog, whichButton ->
//                //do something with edt.getText().toString();
//
//                // Add Name in list
//                nameList.add(editText.text.toString())
//                // Handler code here.
//                val intent = Intent(this, NewKitListActivity::class.java)
//                startActivity(intent);
//
//            })
//            dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", { dialog, whichButton ->
//                //pass
//            })
//            val b = dialogBuilder.create()
//            b.show()
//        }
}
```

For completeness: I found the `MainActivity`in `gatekeepersample/java/com.greyblocks.gatekeepersample/MainActivity.kt`. I have been able to add a button in the layout at `gatekeeper/res/layout/activity_main.xml`, and inside that button I am able to display alert dialogs. However my question remains how to display alert dialogs outside the MainActivity without modifying the layout. The comments have suggested to do it through a "service". I am looking into that.

Comment: To show dialog outside of activities I uses Service. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, I have not yet tried that, I am looking up what it is and how it works.

Comment: Well in the Service I start an activity that only contain a dialog. You can also achieve what you want with Broadcast and Receiver I think.

Comment: yes u can do it by making default alert dialog in service. as Service has its own context so no need of making activity inside service for alert dialog. when you get desired result then show this dialog

Comment: Thank you very much for the confirmation. Would you happen to know any such example? I have not yet been able to find an example that does not contain the  `MainActivity`. That means I currently do not know whether the `activity.xml` should go in `/res/xml/` as a separate file, or whether I should paste the `.xml` content into the `authenticator.xml` which is already present in the repository.